# Calculations on Python lists?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have this list:

```
[[54.1757, 57.7807], [61.5786, 64.1535], [67.9584, 83.0], [104.4185, 120.377]]
```

What I want to do is to translate this list into a format where I have a string:

```
first_number:second_number-first_number
```

for each pair in my list. So for the first pair, I would get the following string:

```
"54.1757:3.605"
```

Any suggestions on the best way to implement this?

Comment: The first pair would actually be: `54.1757:-3.605`, unless you want the absolute value, or are actually doing `first_number:second_number-first_number`.

Comment: Ooops, good catch. Should be second_number-first_number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
In [1]: arr = [[54.1757, 57.7807], [61.5786, 64.1535], [67.9584, 83.0], [104.4185, 120.377]]

In [2]: arr2 = [ "{}:{}".format(a, a-b) for a, b in arr ]

In [3]: arr2
Out[3]:
['54.1757:-3.605', '61.5786:-2.5749', '67.9584:-15.0416', '104.4185:-15.9585']
```

Comment: A dictionary comprehension doesn't maintain the order.

Comment: I got `{104.41850000000001: -15.958499999999987, 54.175700000000006: -3.6049999999999969, 61.578600000000002: -2.5748999999999924, 67.958399999999997: -15.041600000000003}` with your code.

Comment: Good point, I didn't think about the order. My updated answer uses a list comprehension instead.

Comment: Also, why do you have `In [1]:` and stuff?

Comment: I just tried this, and it looks like it works. I'm actually quite amazed at how succinct the code is to do this. Was not familiar with using .format. Thank you.

Comment: @mbomb007: I use `In [1]:` etc to match the [iPython command shell](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/interactive/reference.html).

Comment: It'd be better without it. Most people probably don't use a shell.

Comment: @mbomb007: I think it's a concise way to show what's code/input versus output. The other answer to this question uses a different shell notation.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to do using list comprehension.

```
>>> list = [[54.1757, 57.7807], [61.5786, 64.1535], [67.9584, 83.0], [104.4185, 120.377]]
>>>
>>> [ {x:y-x} for x, y in list ]
[{54.1757: 3.605000000000004}, {61.5786: 2.5748999999999924}, {67.9584: 15.041600000000003}, {104.4185: 15.9585}]
>>>
```

Comment: The output is supposed to be a list of strings.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Missed that part.